# Transparent viewmodels on TF2

Tags: team-fortress-2, mods

As a sniper/spy main, it is important to know your surroundings whether it is to avoid backstabs or create opportunities for them.  But an opaque weapon (along with hands during reloads) in your bottom right corner isn't exactly helping.

**Why not just turn off your viewmodel?** It feels empty to shoot using a weapon that you're not (visibly) holding.  In some cases, it makes it harder to aim as well (e.g. projectile weapons).

I've seen a few YouTubers (e.g. [MrPaladin](https://www.youtube.com/user/MrPaladin1176)) using transparent viewmodels. But none of them show how it's done.

Does anyone know how to set a transparent viewmodel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MrPaladin (and others) are using [ToonHUD](http://toonhud.com): a customizable HUD for Team Fortress 2. It comes with an easy configuration tool (below), of which one option that you can enable/disable is transparent viewmodels.

[image: ToonHUD's config screen]

You can also see MrPaladin's video where he goes through his config here: